# Creating a T-table with a bold lines in LaTeX

Tags: tables, formatting

**Could you help me to draw this T-table in LaTeX?**

[image: TABLE]

**I'am using this code :**

```
\begin{tabular}{ l| l}
            \hline
            \textbf{CLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.}  & Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum. \\
            \textbf{Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since.} & Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero. \\
            \textbf{Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.} & The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum \\
\end{tabular}
```

**I get this result :**

[image]

**Difficulties :**

1. the table exceed the page
2. change line thickness
3. change the height of a row
4. change the width of a column

*Thank you!*

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! What is exactly difficult for you? It is a standard tabular with two columns and a vertical rule in between. Do you have special requriements?

Comment: What is exactly difficult for you? It is standard `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\hrule`, `\vrule`.

Comment: @wipet I edited my question so you can see the difficulties I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be closer to the expected output:

[image]

In order to overcome the mentioned issues, I did the following changes in comparison to the oiginal code:

- Used a fixed width column type for the first column. Since the `p` type column, which would be the obvious choice for the left column of your table sets its contents justified and you apparently want ragged right alignment instead, I defined the new `L` column type. In order to get rid of the repeated use of `\textbf` for all entries in the first column, I added `>{\bfseries}`. The width of the column can of course be adjusted to suit your needs.
- Used `tabularx` instead of `tabular` in order to make sure the table does not exceed a given overall width. Its `X` type column is automatically as wide as the remaining space that is not yet occupied by other table columns. Since the `X` type column also justifies its contents, I defined the `Z` type column for ragged right alignment.
- To change the widths of the horizontal and vertical line, I added `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}`. If you add this command to the preamble, it will affect all tables in your document. If you use it somewhere inside the document, it affects all following tables. If you want to change the lines of just one tabular, enclose it and the command in a set of `{}, just as I did in the MWE. YOu can of course adjust the width argument to suit your needs.
- In order to increase the row heights, I added `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`. You can also adjust the factor to your liking.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

{
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\bfseries}L{5.25cm} | Z}
            \hline
            CLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. & Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum. \\
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since. & Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero. \\
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard. & The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum \\
\end{tabularx}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @leandriis , that's exactly what I'm looking for.